# mongoldb compare time with now and delete some

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following data.

```
id:27199997
condition:"in_progress"
date:2017-11-17 19:06:36.820

id:27199998
condition:"in_progress"
date:2017-11-17 20:07:36.820

id:27199999
condition:"in_progress"
date:2017-11-17 21:09:36.820
```

From this I want to delete dates with date > 1 hour from now

I've tried like `db.collection.find_one({"condition": "in_progress", "date":{ "$gt": last }})`

btw

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

last = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=0, hours=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you should have used lt instead of gt and - instead of +

```
last = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=0, hours=1)
db.collection.find_one({"condition": "in_progress", "date":{ "$lt": last }})
```